# VSTO C# Outlook send files via POST, Outlook get no response till upload is done

Tags: post, outlook, progress-bar, vsto

My VSTO Addin sending from Outlook - files and data to API. My problem is when i upload for example file about 10 MB, Outlook get status `No response` till upload finish.

When add ProgressBar - becouse is part of outlook Freeze too.

My question is, did anybody face same problem and solve it ? Or is possible to VSTO Outlook addin add `WPF` Progress Bar ?

thanks for tips

UPDATE for @Dmitry Streblechenko

Attachment from email is stored locally and send via RestClient:

```
var client2 = new RestClient("https://my.web.com/api/upload");
client2.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("id", RiD);
request.AddFile("file_path", @"C:\attachment\attachment.zip");
IRestResponse response = client2.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

How to send it in secondary thread ?

Thanks

Comment: Why not upload the data in a separate thread? You cannot access OOM object in a secondary thread, but you can save the data locally on the main thread, and then upload it to your server on a secondary thread.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko cna you please take a look on my update ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to use the Thread object? Or how to run code asynchronously using, for example, the Task object?

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko in your first answer " store file locally and upload it to your server on a secondary thread", but how to achive ? second thread means create another addin for outlook handlo uploud files only ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution help me:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
 {
     Thread.Sleep(3000);
     var client2 = new RestClient("https://my.web.com/api/upload");
     client2.Timeout = 5000;
     var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
     request.AddParameter("id", RiD);
     request.AddFile("file_path", @"C:\attachment\attachment.zip");
     IRestResponse response = client2.Execute(request);
     Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
  });

  thread.Start();
  thread.IsBackground = true;
```

note: `Thread.Sleep(3000);` is there becouse main thread - zip all attachments in email, so i need slow second threat to wait for zip

thanks  @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: Firstly, instead of calling Sleep(), actually wait for the operation to finish, and then start the thread. Also, do not hardcode the attachment path